# Re-assigning a string to character pointer in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, variable-assignment, string-literals

May be my concepts about pointer are not clear but I have a doubt. For integer pointer

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a = 4;
int *b = &a;
*b = 6;
printf("%d", *b);
}
```

prints

```
6
```

but for character pointer

```
char *str = "Hello";
*str = "Hlw";
```

gives error
but

```
char *str = "Hello";
str = "Hlw";
```

Works. So, why does it work like this?

Comment: *gives error but* -- You should post the error message that is given and tell us what in the error message you are having trouble with.

Comment: [No errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abe25df715526e8e) just warnings. And these are quite clearly expressed.

Comment: The latter is not proper C++.

Answer (score 4):

A string literal is a `const char[]` array, which decays into a `const char*` pointer to the string's 1st `char`.

`char *str = "Hello";` is legal in C, and in C++ up to C++03, but is illegal in C++11 and later.  Modern versions do not allow a `const char*` pointer to be assigned to a non-const `char*` pointer (without an explicit type-cast, anyay).

Just as `*b` in your `int*` example accesses a single `int`, so too does `*str` access a single `char`.  So `*str = "Hlw";` is trying to assign a `const char*` pointer to a single `char`, which it why it fails to compile.

`str = "Hlw";` is simply assigning a `const char*` pointer to `str`, making it point at a different memory address (if that were legal).  In terms of your `int*` example, that would be the same as doing this:

```cpp
int a;
int *b = &a;
int c;
b = &c; // <--
```

Comment: So, when I write ```*str = "hlw" ``` It assigns starting address of string to *s which is incorrect ```s = "hlw"```but it is ok if we assign starting address to only str

Comment: @AdityaKomawar yes

Answer (score 1):

When you indirect through an `int*`, you get lvalue to `int`. An `int` is an integer.

When you indirect through a  `char*`, you get lvalue to `char`. A `char` is not a string. It is a single character (assuming fixed width character encoding rather than unicode).

The core difference here is that strings are arrays of characters, while integers are not arrays.

> ```
> str = "Hlw";
> ```

This is ill-formed in C++ because string literal is an array of const char, and such array does not implicitly convert to a pointer to non-const char.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers do not have an information whether they point to a single object or to a member of an array.

In this code snippet

```
int *b = &a;
*b = 6;
```

the pointer `p` points to an object of the type `int`, so dereferencing the pointer you will get an access to this object.

In this code snippet

```
char *str = "Hello";
*str = "Hlw";
```

the pointer `str` points to an object of the type `char`. It points to the first character of the string literal `"Hello"`. So dereferencing the pointer you will get an access to the first character of the string literal pointed to by the pointer.

Hence instead of this incorrect assignment

```
*str = "Hlw";
```

where the left hand side operand has the type `char` while the right hand side operand has the type `char[4]` in C and `const char[4]` in C++ you should write something like

```
*str = 'G';
```

that is you may assign a character literal to an object of the type `char`. You may not assign a string literal to an object of the type char like for example

```
char c = "Hello";
```

and the expression `*str` indeed has the type `char`.

In this code snippet

```
char *str = "Hello";
str = "Hlw";
```

you are reassigning the pointer `str` itself instead of the pointed by it object.

After the declaration the pointer str points to the first character of the string literal `"Hello"` that is to the character `'H'`.

In the following statement the pointer `str` is reassigned by the address of the first character of the string literal `"Hlw"`. That ijs now it points to the character `'H'` of this string literal.

Answer (score 0):

`*b` can be replaced by `b[0]` because, in C, a pointer to anything is also an array of one element of that type. Doing this way helps to understand the issue :

```
int a = 4;
int *b = &a;
b[0] = 6;       //<=== this is correct because b is an array of int

char *str = "Hello";
str[0] = "Hlw"; //<=== but this is not as explained by other answers
```